# How to add a word per minute calculator to a website using Javascript, html, or css?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

Iv'e been trying to complete a typing test website for some time and am stuck on how to add a word per minute counter. I have tried multiple ways but none of them work. What I want it do do is give the words per minute after the user types a prompt correctly.
Code is below:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<h1>
   <span id="word-1">man</span> <span id="word-2">become</span> <span id="word-3">as</span>
   <span id="word-4">and</span> <span id="word-5">through</span> <span id="word-6">find</span> <span id="word-7">would</span> <span id="word-8">here</span> <span id="word-9">and</span> <span id="word-10">before</span>
</h1>

<input type="text" id="boch">

        </div>
        <div id="typing-area">

      <button id="bocho" onclick="document.getElementById('boch').value = ''">Enter</button>

</html>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
var input = document.getElementById("boch");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("bocho").click();
  }
});


var element = document.querySelector("#boch");

element.onkeyup = function () {
  var value = element.value;

  if (value.includes("man")) {
    document.getElementById('word-1').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-1').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  }

  if (value.includes("man become")) {
    document.getElementById('word-2').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-2').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as")) {
    document.getElementById('word-3').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-3').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and")) {
    document.getElementById('word-4').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-4').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through")) {
    document.getElementById('word-5').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-5').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through find")) {
    document.getElementById('word-6').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-6').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through find would")) {
    document.getElementById('word-7').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-7').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through find would here")) {
    document.getElementById('word-8').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-8').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through find would here and")) {
    document.getElementById('word-9').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-9').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  }

  if (value.includes("man become as and through find would here and before")) {
    document.getElementById('word-10').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('word-10').style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
  }

 

}
let tagArr = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (let i = 0; i < tagArr.length; i++) {
  tagArr[i].autocomplete = 'off';
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Irfan

Comment: Can you be more specific? What did you try? What does not work? You provide a lot of code, but as I read your question the stylesheets should not be relevant for example

Comment: your HTML doesn't have a `<BODY>`

Comment: I tried using some code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-a-typing-speed-test-game-using-javascript/ but it did not work. I removed the CSS. I'm also new to javascript.

Comment: How would you define "words per minute"? Do you mean tracking the time it takes to type each word and then divide by the number of words? What is your expected algorithm for the typing? What should trigger the start and end of typing and what defines a 'word'? Is "a" a word or "do" ?

Comment: The defintion of Words per minute is how many words a person can type in 60 seconds. I don't really know what algorithm to use because the amount of words in it are too less.

Comment: script after html?

Comment: There is a standard way to figure the words per minute that takes into account the error rate, not just how _much_ you typed. I don't know what the formula is, but giyf. Does your current code calculate something, but it's not what you expect? What in particular is not working?

Comment: Well I went and googled it and got https://www.speedtypingonline.com/typing-equations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to store the current timestamp in a variable when a key is pressed for the first time.
Then, when the user have finish, get the difference between the current timestamp and the timestamp stored at the start.
Next, you have to calculate the elapsed time and convert it to words per minute.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

To avoid your multiple if-else structures, you can split the string by spaces, then compare word by word in a for loop.

```js
const string = "man become as and through find would here and before";

var text = document.getElementById("text");
var input = document.getElementById("input");

var start = null;
var finished = false;

// Split the string to an array of words
var words = string.split(" ");

text.innerHTML = "";
// For each word, add it as a span element in the text
words.forEach(w => {
    let el = document.createElement("span");
    el.innerText = w;
    text.appendChild(el);
    text.innerHTML += " ";
});

input.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
    // Split the input to an array of words
    let input_words = input.value.split(" ");
    let good = true;

    if (finished)
        return;
    if (!start)
        start = Date.now();

    // Iterate over all the words
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        let element = words[i];
        // If the word is not the same as the word at same position in the input, set 'good' at false
        if (input_words[i] != element)
            good = false;
        // Set the background color for the word, selecting the element
        // by the parent's children index (corresponding to i) to avoid the usage of ids
        text.children[i].style.backgroundColor = good ? "green" : null;
    }
    // If all words are correct, the variable is still true
    if (good)
    {
        finished = true;
        // Get the difference in seonds between start and now
        let elapsed = (Date.now() - start) / 1000;
        // Get words per seconde
        let words_per_seconde = words.length * 60 / elapsed;
        // Round to the fourth decimal
        words_per_seconde = Math.round(words_per_seconde * 1000) / 1000;
        alert(words_per_seconde + " words per minute.");
    }
});
```

```html
<h1 id="text"></h1>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="input"/>
```

Comment: Don't use `on` handlers unless you're creating a brand new element. Use addEventListener instead.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  var start, end, elapsed;

  function split(str) {
    return str.split(" ");
  }

  function compWords(a, b) {
    $.each(a, function(i, w) {
      console.log(w, b.eq(i).text());
      if (w == b.eq(i).text()) {
        $(".word").eq(i).removeClass("incorrect").addClass("correct");
      } else {
        $(".word").eq(i).removeClass("correct").addClass("incorrect");
      }
    });
  }

  function showTime(ms) {
    var minutes = Math.floor(ms / 60000);
    var seconds = ((ms % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
    var result = minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds;
    var wordLength = $(".word").length
    alert(result + " to type " + wordLength + " words. " + $(".word.correct").length + " correct. " + Math.round(wordLength * 60 / seconds) + " WPM");
  }

  $("#boch").keydown(function(e) {
    if ($(this).val().length == 1) {
      start = Date.now();
      $(".word").removeClass("correct incorrect");
    }
  }).keyup(function(e) {
    var typed = $(this).val();
    compWords(split(typed), $(".word"));
  });

  $("#bocho").click(function() {
    if (start != undefined) {
      end = Date.now();
      elapsed = end - start;
      showTime(elapsed);
    }
  });

  $("#typing-area form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#bocho").click();
  });
});
```

```css
.word {
  padding: .025em;
}

.word.correct {
  background-color: #cfc;
}

.word.incorrect {
  background-color: #fcc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  <span class="word">man</span> <span class="word">become</span> <span class="word">as</span>
  <span class="word">and</span> <span class="word">through</span> <span class="word">find</span> <span class="word">would</span> <span class="word">here</span> <span class="word">and</span> <span class="word">before</span>
</h1>
<div id="typing-area">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="boch" autocomplete="off" />
    <button id="bocho">Enter</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

This takes similar code and shows you how you can calculate the time it takes the User to type the words. It will not calculate the WPM since there are too few words. You might consider extrapolating the ratio. Words * 60 / Seconds.

This answer uses jQuery. You can use JavaScript to do this as well if you choose.

Comment: Thanks but it does not work. I tried replacing my code with this but none of the features would work.

Comment: @IrfanS did you add the jQuery library o your head? If still having an issue, please update you original post (OP).